# How to Resolve 'Cannot Find Module' Error in Angular for 'angular2-signaturepad/signature-pad'?

Tags: angular, typescript, signaturepad

```
I'm installed 'npm install angular2-signaturepad --save'.

Angular CLI: 10.1.5.

I am getting this error.
How to fix?
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried to fix this.

npm install angular2-signaturepad@latest

Install and update the 'angular2-signaturepad' library.

Then tried importing SignaturePad,AngularSignaturePadModule.forRoot() and SignaturePadModule.forRoot() into app.module.ts

Comment: I need to add a signature pad to this project. If this is not possible, is there another option?

Comment: The owner of this package will not update it anymore [see here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-signaturepad), I wouldn't recommend you to keep trying to use it. If I were you, I would try to follow [this blog post](https://medium.com/@ganapathy2000subramanian/building-a-signature-pad-in-angular-a-step-by-step-guide-%EF%B8%8F-de3d753568e3) or install another package [like this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@almothafar/angular-signature-pad?activeTab=readme). Just keep in mind that the last update of this package happened a year ago.

Comment: I did as in [this blog](https://medium.com/@ganapathy2000subramanian/building-a-signature-pad-in-angular-a-step-by-step-guide-%EF%B8%8F-de3d753568e3). That's right. @Bruno Rodrigues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did as in [this blog](https://medium.com/@ganapathy2000subramanian/building-a-signature-pad-in-angular-a-step-by-step-guide-%EF%B8%8F-de3d753568e3). That's right.

1. install

> npm install @almothafar/angular-signature-pad --save

2. create a new component

> ng generate component signaturePad

3. In the app.module.ts 'declarations' are updated.

```html
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SignaturePadComponent } from './component/shared/signature-pad/signature-pad.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SignaturePadComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

4. Update signature-pad.component.ts and signature-pad.component.html as follows

```js
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import SignaturePad from 'signature_pad';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signature-pad',
  templateUrl: './signature-pad.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signature-pad.component.scss']
})
export class SignaturePadComponent implements OnInit {
  signatureNeeded!: boolean;
  signaturePad!: SignaturePad;
  @ViewChild('canvas') canvasEl!: ElementRef;
  signatureImg!: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.signaturePad = new SignaturePad(this.canvasEl.nativeElement);
  }

  startDrawing(event: Event) {
    // works in device not in browser
  }

  moved(event: Event) {
    // works in device not in browser
  }

  clearPad() {
    this.signaturePad.clear();
  }

  savePad() {
    const base64Data = this.signaturePad.toDataURL();
    this.signatureImg = base64Data;
    this.signatureNeeded = this.signaturePad.isEmpty();
    if (!this.signatureNeeded) {
      this.signatureNeeded = false;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h4>Please Add your signature here</h4>
<canvas
  #canvas
  (touchstart)="startDrawing($event)"
  (touchmove)="moved($event)"
  width="150"
  height="100"
></canvas>
<p class="error-message" *ngIf="signatureNeeded">Signature is required</p>

<div class="buttons flex justify-between">
  <button (click)="clearPad()">Clear</button>
  <button (click)="savePad()">Submit the signature</button>
</div>

<div *ngIf="signatureNeeded === false">
  <p>Signature in Base64Encoded Format</p>
  <img src="{{ signatureImg }}" alt="" srcset="" />
</div>
```

5. Use the selector where necessary

> 

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)